# How can I get the width and height of a div element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, width, parseint

How can I get the width and height of a div element?

for instance,

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden; float:left; margin:0px 0px 5px 0px; border:1px solid #000;">
    <img src="daisy_03_20110712163828_extra.jpg" alt="daisy_03_20110712163828_extra.jpg" width="800" height="589" id="preview"/>
</div>
```

I tried with this method,

```
var previewwidth = $("#preview").css('width');
var previewheight = $("#preview").css('height');
```

But I get `800px` which is the width of the image instead!

I want to get the `100` as `number` actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$("#preview")` which will return the img since the img tag is the one with `id="preview"`

**First option**:

```
$("#preview").parent().css('width');
```

**Second, better option**:

Give the div an id, say "foofoo":

```
<div id="foodoo">...</div>
$("#foofoo").css('width');
```

To **make it into an integer** wrap in `parseInt()`:

```
parseInt($("#foofoo").css('width'));
```

Comment: Using `.css()` will give a result as a string, not a number.

Answer (score 3):

Give the div an id, and use that instead of the id of your image.

Comment: I agree, do this in favour of slowing things down with an unnecessary parent selector.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 potential methods of doing this:

### One:

```
$("#preview").parent().css('width');
$("#preview").parent().css('height');
```

### Two:

```
$("#preview").parent().width();
$("#preview").parent().height();
```

This will *not* include margins, padding and border.

### Three:

```
$("#preview").parent().outerWidth();
$("#preview").parent().outerHeight();
```

This will include the padding, border, and optionally margin. To include margin you must add `true` in the function, i.e. `.outerHeight(true)`.

- [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/)
- [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/)
- [outerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)
- [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

Comment: but, as pointed out earlier, would still be better to giv the div an id

Answer (score 1):

```
var previewwidth = $("#preview").parent().width();
var previewheight = $("#preview").parent().height();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width). Look at the [API](http://api.jquery.com/) for these sorts of questions..

Also, as pointed out above, your selector isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

`preview` is the ID of your image so of course your code is returning the size of the image.  Just give your div a different unique ID, and use that instead of `#preview` in your jQuery selector.

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden; float:left; margin:0px 0px 5px 0px; border:1px solid #000;">
    <img src="daisy_03_20110712163828_extra.jpg" alt="daisy_03_20110712163828_extra.jpg" width="800" height="589" id="preview"/>
</div>
```

The following will return the width/height of the div as "100px":

```
var previewwidth = $("#myDiv").css('width');
var previewheight = $("#myDiv").css('height');
```

And to get the result as a unit-less number instead of a string:

```
var previewwidth = $("#myDiv").width();
var previewheight = $("#myDiv").height();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply like that ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3SuT/) as an example):

```
var mydiv = jQuery('#preview').parent('div');
var mywidth = mydiv.width();
var myheight = mydiv.height();
```